# How to read a page that uses JS to block scraping?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin (C#). I tried this code to get data I need in my app:

```
String url = "http://mmehdirajabiigdl.gigfa.com/VideoImageDownloader.php?link=https://www.instagram.com/tv/CJ_YPTLJ8Zx/?igshid=1jcvto1p6ekxx";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string mm = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

The response is wrong because this page is using JS that blocks my codes from getting HTML codes.
Well how can I fix this? I know WebRequest has no "Enabling JS". Maybe I should use WebBrowser but Xamarin has no WebBrowser.

Comment: if you're trying to scrape data from a page that actively prevents it, maybe you should consider that you are not legally entitled to use their data?

Comment: @Jason It's my own web hosting but the provider didn't disable JS so It's always blocking me from scraping my own datas.Going to another webhosting maybe fix this problem but I'm looking for way to fix this without transfering my datas to another webhosting service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i know, HttpWebRequest just does a HTTP request and you could scrape the static HTML. It does not support JavaScript.

You could execute Javascript with Xamarin Forms `WebView`.

For more details, please check the link below. https://www.xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-webview-executing-javascript/